Error_log AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown' How to show fileName
After migrating to php-fpm when I try to access to an unexisting file I get
AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown'

in Apache2 error log.
How can I get the filename with a full path in the error log?
